# Is 去年に grammatical?

Tags: grammar

I know the rules regarding when to use に with time expressions and when not to. Or at least, I thought I knew the rules. But I watched an ANN news item about Tsukiji market today, and at one point the presenter says「去年に...」. I thought this was not possible grammatically.

Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-smsxUWXys

At 05:00 the presenter says これに対して去年**に**事業者が。。。

I thought it would have to be これに対して去年、事業者が。。。

Is there a definitive guide to which 'time words' will allow に and which will definitely not?

Answer (score 2):

I found 16 similar instances of 去年に on BCCWJ (excluding ones where に is clearly needed, such as 去年に続いて, 去年に比べて). This is definitely not a large number. Personally, 去年に does not sound terribly bad, and I feel even a native speaker may occasionally say it, especially in speech. But it's still unnatural and you should avoid it when possible. The same is true for 明日に, 昨日に, and so on.

Comment: I agree that it is probably avoided, but the fact that native speakers use it is somewhat interesting to me. I'd like to know why this is possible at all.